# A floating-point rounding problem

Tags: floating-point, python

I run the Python code below. `x` and `y` differ in their 4th and 5th number, and `x` has larger values. The program correctly shows that there is a difference between the two sums, and the difference is not that small. I therefore expect that the sum for `y` is smaller than the sum for 'x'. However, it shows that `x` has the same value as `y`. The floating-point rounding could obviously contribute to this problem. But I am very puzzled by why the two sums are **identical**. If I change `range(5)` to `range(3,5)` (i.e., including only the two different values), the results do show different sums.

I obtained these results from two approaches to solving a problem. One approach is expected to be more accurate than the other, because only one division is performed, while the other approach performs many divisions.

````
x = [0.333333333333333314829616256247, \
0.133333333333333331482961625625, \
0.057142857142857141072855853281, \
0.025396825396825396803368590781, \
0.011544011544011544001531177628]

y = [0.333333333333333314829616256247, \
0.133333333333333331482961625625, \
0.057142857142857141072855853281, \
0.025396825396825393333921638828, \
0.011544011544011542266807701651]

diff = 0
sum_x = 0
sum_y = 0
for i in range(5):
    diff += x[i]-y[i]
    sum_x += x[i]
    sum_y += y[i]

print(f'{diff:.60f}')
print(f'{sum_x:.60f}')
print(f'{sum_y:.60f}')
```
````

Comment: This looks a programming question. Please find [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on/129632#129632). Revisit the caption of tag [python](/tags/python/info).

Comment: This is a well known side effect of subtracting two floating point numbers that are very close together.  This and other side effects of floating point numbers are covered in Numerical Analysis college courses.

Comment: The 1st to 3rd start with 0.33, 0.13, 0.05, if they all start with 0.01 they work as intended. Python float corresponds to C++ double as defined in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), keeping roughly 15 most significant figures. The difference between 4th to 5th barely makes it into the significant figures, and adding the larger 1st to 3rd means the difference can't be stored.

Comment: @SteveMathwig I don't believe your answer holds if the difference is just a bit closer than OP's example.

Comment: @KennethKho, I encourage you to write that as an answer so we can upvote it and the question can be treated as answered.  (That already seems sufficient to constitute an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Python `float` corresponds to C++ `double`. According to Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), `double` or `binary64` is specified with:

- Sign bit: $1$ bit
- Exponent: $11$ bits
- Significand precision: $53$ bits ($52$ explicitly stored)

The 53-bit significand precision gives from $15$ to $17$ significant decimal digits precision ($2^{−53}$ ≈ $1.11 × 10^{−16}$).

Notice $x[3]$ and $y[3]$ share identical $16$ significant decimal digits precision `2539682539682539`, and $x[4]$ and $y[4]$ share identical $16$ significant decimal digits precision `1154401154401154`.

They only differ in the $17$th significant decimal digits precision. This is nearing its limit, and only works because the first digit is smaller. This is lost with the larger $x[0], x[1], x[2], y[0], y[1], y[2]$.

We can see that this is no longer erroneous when we change the largest decimal places of $x[0], x[1], x[2], y[0], y[1], y[2]$ to $0.01$ as follows:

```
x = [0.013333333333333314829616256247, \
0.013333333333333331482961625625, \
0.017142857142857141072855853281, \
0.025396825396825396803368590781, \
0.011544011544011544001531177628]

y = [0.013333333333333314829616256247, \
0.013333333333333331482961625625, \
0.017142857142857141072855853281, \
0.025396825396825393333921638828, \
0.011544011544011542266807701651]
```